# OSX - Copy Automator tasks from one machine to another

Tags: macos, sync, automator

Where does OSX save automator tasks? I would like to use my current set of tasks on another machine running OSX.

Comment: You should also be concerned about security.  macOS might prevent the App from running on a remote machine because it's from an unauthorized developer.  https://superuser.com/questions/973662/automator-app-wont-open-after-being-copied-to-another-computer-osx

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Automator doesn't seem to directly name anything a 'task' so **here's a few predictions as to what you meant by 'task'**:</sup>

- #### Workflow or Application

  This depends where you saved the file. If you saved it to iCloud, you can find them here:

  ```
  open ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Automator/Documents
  ```

  If you saved it elsewhere, copy them from wherever you saved them.
- #### Service

  If you saved your workflow as a service, then they can be accessed here:

  ```
  open ~/Library/Services
  ```
- #### Action

  Drag it into a workflow, right-click and choose Show in Finder.