# Automator app won't open after being copied to another computer - OSX

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, script, automator

I created an app in Automator. The app runs fine on the computer with which I created it, but when I copy it to another computer I get:

```
The application “AppX” can’t be opened.
```

If I open it in Automator (on the destination computer) and click File->Duplicate (saving it in the same directory), the duplicate runs fine. I'm assuming there is a permissions issue, but I'm not sure what it is or how to fix it. I would like to be able to copy this app to various computers and just double click it to run with out having to mess with permissions first. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Technically I'm copying it from my computer to an OSX VM running on my computer. I have tried dragging and dropping (so copying through Parallels) and uploading/downloading with Dropbox, with the same results both ways.

Comment: Exactly how are you copying it to the other computer?

Comment: @GordonDavisson So technically I'm copying it from my computer to an OSX VM running on my computer. I tried dragging and dropping (so copying through Parallels) and uploading/downloading with Dropbox, with the same results both ways.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The issue probably isn't the copy to another machine but the copy itself. I found that execute permission was removed from yourappname.app/Contents/MacOS/yourappname during the copy. When I restored the permission with chmod +x yourappname.app/Contents/MacOS/yourappname I was able to execute the application

Comment: In my case, the command was $ chmod +x my-automator.app/Contents/MacOS/Application\ Stub

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem with my app scripts not working when copied, and other types of apps I transferred. (Not just app scripts.) It turns out the copy operation was not preserving execute permissions.

Comment: These solutions both worked: 1) Your chmod fix, or 2) Zip the apps before copy, and unzip from the target computer. That would preserve the execute flags during transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it again and when you see:

```
The application “AppX” can’t be opened.
```

Go to System Preferences... Security and Privacy. Under the General tab there should be a temporary option under

```
Allow apps downloaded from:
```

allowing you to run your app. It's a consequence  Apple's ever expanding Gatekeeper protection.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491